# Comparing bool and string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

I have a search method and I want to search the bool value in the table. IsFallBack is bool and displaying in the table as true or false.

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchIsFallBack))
            {
                tableData = (IOrderedQueryable<TableData>)tableData.Where(m => m.IsFallBack.ToString() == searchIsFallBack);
            }
```

When I try to search program throws an exception: **System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression could not be translated.**

[image]

searchValue is the value that the user enters tı the search box
How can I compare the bool value and searched value?

Comment: What are the possible values of `searchIsFallBack`?

Comment: I think the problem is because you try to cast it to IOrderedQueryable. First maybe you should cast it to Queryable?: tableData = (blabla)tableData.Where().ToQueryable()

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras user can enter the search box "true" or "false". If the user enters false, the user wants to see only false rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchIsFallBack))
    {
        if(searchIsFallBack == "true")
        {
            tableData = (IOrderedQueryable<TableData>)tableData.Where(m => m.IsFallBack);
        }
        else
        {
            tableData = (IOrderedQueryable<TableData>)tableData.Where(m => !m.IsFallBack);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the issue is that EF can not translate `ToString()`. One solution is to translate the string to bool instead (which would be a lot more performant too, as you will be searching the native DB type, instead of performing a conversion on every row):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchIsFallBack))
{
    tableData = (IOrderedQueryable<TableData>)tableData.Where(m => 
       m.IsFallBack == (searchIsFallBack == "true"));
}
```